# How quickly does one receive the electronic visit pass by email after going through the immigration in Singapore?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, singapore

I read the following when going over the [Arrival Card](https://eservices.ica.gov.sg/sgarrivalcard/) form for Singapore:

[image: If you are eligible for entry into Singapore, you will receive an electronic visit pass (in lieu of inked endorsement stamps on the passport) sent to you via this email address. Please therefore ensure that you provide a valid email address. Please note that the email address is automatically set in uppercase format for clarity purpose.]

Text:

> If you are eligible for entry into Singapore, you will receive an electronic visit pass (in lieu of inked endorsement stamps on the passport) sent to you via this email address. Please therefore ensure that you provide a valid email address. Please note that the email address is automatically set in uppercase format for clarity purpose.

It is echoed by https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-transit-depart/entering-singapore/visa_requirements:

> From 11 March 2022, all foreign visitors arriving in Singapore will be notified digitally of their Visit Pass (e-Pass) through email. There will not be any endorsement on your passport. The e-Pass notification will indicate the period of stay granted and last day of stay allowed. Please ensure that you provide a valid email address when submitting the SG Arrival Card.

How quickly does one receive the electronic visit pass by email after going through the immigration in Singapore? Is that instantaneous, or does it take a few minutes, a few hours or a few days?

Comment: I wonder about the "Please note that the email address is automatically set in uppercase format for clarity purpose". In theory local parts of email addresses are case sensitive. Of course in practice no major provider will treat them like that, but still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked my emails, and last May, 2023, it took almost 2 days. In September, 7 minutes. I think in May there was a glitch, and the 7-minute response is probably more the norm...

Comment: On 2023-11-18 I received the "Notification of Electronic Visit Pass" at 1451, according to the body of that email I went through immigration at 1439 (so ~12 minutes.)

Comment: Can confirm I also had the email before I had my bags...